# How to write data to HDFS running on docker container using kafka from local machine?

Tags: docker, hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs

I'm new to docker, as well as Kafka and hdfs. I'm running a docker container with hdfs. And I need to move data from MongoDB to HDFS using kafka. I installed kafka on the local machine and I was able to connect it to the mongo BD. Now, I want to know how can I connect kafka to hdfs which is running on a docker container.

Comment: Do you really need Kafka for this? Spark alone would work fine, but Kafka Connect is what you can use https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-hdfs/current/index.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer I need to implement lambda architecture for real-time analytics. can spark along does this?

Comment: The only reason you'd use Kafka is to buffer data or expose it to other processes. To solve the problem of moving data between Mongo and HDFS, Kafka is not necessary

Comment: @OneCricketeer can we directly use MongoDB data in spark structured streaming as well?

Comment: You can read collections into dataframes or write streaming dataframes into collections, yes. You don't need streaming between Mongo and HDFS, though, just SparkSQL